# Not Enough Disk Space to Save File Mounted Image Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

I have mounted an android system.img in my Ubuntu virtual machine using the command line code `sudo mount -t ext4 -o loop system.img sys/` The mounting process goes just fine, I can open up the fiels to read them, but the second that I try to edit a subfile and save it it says "Not enough disk space to save the file".

On the virtual machine itself I have plenty of space, but the file folder that this image is mounted out of has zero space remaining. Does anybody know a way to be able to edit and save these files? I already tried exporting them to a different folder but nothing has worked thus far.

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [resize2fs](http://linux.die.net/man/8/resize2fs) to resize the volume.  I've done this in order to work around a bug in the Android tools that let you specify the size of the data partition (which didn't work at the time, so I had to resize the partition myself).  I also just tested this against a system.img that came from an Android system image from the SDK.

Comment: Am I trying to re-size the mount or the folder? I really don't have any idea how to use either but I'll try it

Comment: resize2fs will work against the unmounted img file.  I didn't have any idea how to use it either, then I just read the man page.  :-)